# Textbox without spaces in between

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, reporting

I have this SQL table where there are 6 address fields ...

Address 1
Address 2
Address 3
Address 4
Address 5
Address 6

I have to club all the address fields into one text box in ssrs. So that the whole address is displayed in the same text box field.

Plus the condition in the requirement is in the pic below.

[Display the address lines one below the other in the repor. If any field is empty skip and display the next field. Don't leave the space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0umJ.jpg)

I tried using (iif statements) ...but this doesn't seem to help ... Somewhere or the other there were gaps in the text box ..

```
Fields!address1.values & vbcrlf +  Iif(isnothing(fields!address2.values = "",fields!address3,fields!address2.values) Iif(isnothing(fields!address3.values = "",fields!address3,fields!address3.values) Iif(isnothing(fields!address4values = "",fields!address3,fields!address4.values) ....
```

Comment: i am sorry but that didnt help

Answer (score 1):

This would actually likely be easier in the SQL layer. Then you can just use `CONCAT_WS`:

```sql
CONCAT_WS(' ',Address1, Address2, Address3) AS FullAddress
```

Comment: "CONCAT_WS ignores null values during concatenation, and does not add the separator between null values. Therefore, CONCAT_WS can cleanly handle concatenation of strings that might have "blank" values - for example, a second address field." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Nice that the documentation literally calls this scenario out, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use an expression would something in this form work ?

```
iif(isnothing(Fields!address1.values,"", Fields!address1.values & vbcrlf) & 
iif(isnothing(Fields!address2.values,"", Fields!address2.values & vbcrlf) ... etc.
```

Comment: i am sorry but that didnt help

Comment: @Gaurav could you be specific?